# how to type a Value on a dataGrid blazor to update it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm beginner in coding. I try to update the value of stock_quantity of variations displayed in dxGrid.  when i enter the new value for some variations it will be stored in local variable then when i click on a buttom "bulk update" i send the updated variations to the service to be saved on the remote DB woocommerce. Before i used the datagrid only for dislaying variation's informations. when i want to update variations i use popup, type new informations then click on update buttom to execute UpdateVariation .

this is the codes of the dataGrid :

```
`<DxGrid 
    Data="@variations"
    KeyFieldName="id"
    RowDoubleClick="OnVariationDoubleClick"
            ValidationEnabled="false" PagerNavigationMode="PagerNavigationMode.InputBox"
            EditMode="GridEditMode.EditRow" SelectionMode="GridSelectionMode.Single"
            EditorRenderMode="GridEditorRenderMode.Detached"
    VirtualScrollingEnabled="true"
    TextWrapEnabled="true"
            PageSize="10">
    <Columns>
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="id" Caption="ID variation" Width="10%" MinWidth="70" />
            <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="CouleurVariation" Caption="Couleur" Width="25%" MinWidth="100" />
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="TailleVariation" Caption="Taille" Width="10%" />
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="regular_price" Caption="Prix régulier" Width="10%" />
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="stock_quantity" Caption="Qté Stock" Width="15%" >
        <CellEditTemplate>
                @{
                        var detbf = (NewVariationData)context.EditModel;
                        <DxSpinEdit @onkeydown="@((KeyboardEventArgs e) => {checkenvkeydownNavigation(e);})"
                                    @oninput="@((e) => {
                                    var dd=0;
                                    if(Int32.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(),out dd))
                                    @detbf.stock_quantity=Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
                                    StateHasChanged();
                                    GridqterecuMouseUp(detbf, e.Value);
                                    })"
                                    tabindex="2" 
                                    NullText="0" 
                                    MinValue="0"
                                    Value="@detbf.stock_quantity"
                                    DisplayFormat="N0">
                </DxSpinEdit>
                }
            </CellEditTemplate>
         </DxGridDataColumn>`
```

Now I'm stuct in the celledittemplate. My logique is to edit some cells directly in the datagrid,then type on a buttom to send updatedVariations to ProductService .  how can i do that?
thanks